# how to reload a segment of webpage in django?

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates

In django, I am trying to make buttons that change one segment of the webpage by loading html file. The html file shows map and statistics and stuff so they have to be separate. 
My approach was to use ajax call and in the view, return the html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function mapcall (office, year){ 
        console.log(office, year, "clicked")
    $.ajax ({
        method : "GET", 
        url: '/map/', // % url "map" % end point 
        data: {
            office_called: office,
            year_called: year,
        },
        success: function (map){
            console.log("map is here ", map)
            $("#maparea").load($( "{% static 'my_html_return' %}"
            ))},
        error: function (error_data){
        alert("data error, sorry")
        }
    })
}
</script>
<div id="maparea">
    {% if map_return %}
        {% with map_template=map_return|stringformat:"s"|add:".html" %}
            {% include "mypath/"|add:map_template %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

This is my view.py

```
def get_map (request, *args, **kwargs):
year = request.GET.get("year_called")          
office = request.GET.get("office_called") 

map_return = "map"+str(year)+office

return render(request, "mypath/home.html", 
{"title": "Home", "map_return":map_return})
```

I don't know how to make this work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: why not you are using include tag if you have map in another html file

Comment: include in django tag? or in something else?

Comment: By the way, i should mention that the map is actually a html file that contains an image map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to do .html(take html return from ajax as an argument) instead of .load in my case. 
I hope this helps other people.