# Django Selected Radio button choice and dropdown

Tags: python, django

I have created radio button and dropdown menu populated from the static tuple from the Form. I would like to fetch the item what user selected on the same page below the submitting.

FORM.py

```
## VIEW: Populate dropdown to select Data center
def get_role_dc_data(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectionForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'selectsite.html', {'form': form })
    else:
        form = SelectionForm()

    return render(request, 'selectsite.html', {'form': form })

## POPULATE: Data
def gather_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    selectedsite = ''
    roletype = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectionForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            selectedsite = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
            roletype = form.cleaned_data.get('roletype')

        print (selectedsite)
        print (region)

        context_dict = { "selectedsite": selectedsite, "roletype": roletype }
    else:
        context_dict = {}

    return render(request, 'configure.html', context_dict)
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action=/configure/> {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table"><tr><th>
          <label name="roletype" for="region" class="form-check-label">
          Type: {% for choice in form.roletype %}
          <name="roletype"> {{ choice }} {% endfor %}
          </label></th><th>
          <select name="location">
            <datalist id="location">Select an the site</option>
            {% for dc in form.location %}
            <option selected="selected" value="{{ dc }}"></option>
            {% endfor %}</datalist></select></th><th>
          <button align="right" class="button execute" name="submit" value="submit">GO TO</button>
        </th></tr></table></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to display the selected choices without submitting the form, right?

In that case you´d have to render and return this specific part of your page seperately (using javascript - ajax might come in handy as well).
I did something similar before but i need to look it up as well.

Comment: Do you have any example to follow

Comment: These might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978693/how-to-reload-a-segment-of-webpage-in-django

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-ajax-request-in-django/

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

You only need this if you want to display the selection without reloading the entire page. If you work with the submit button you only have to add the information to your context dict.